# iostream equivalent formatter to cstdio "%c"?

Tags: c++, format, iostream

I'm trying to use C++ idioms to write a character to `cout`, but I can't find a character formatter in any of the C++ standard libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chars are automatically formatted like %c. To print integer as char (if you really want to), you can convert it:

```
int x = 42;
std::cout << (char) x;
```

Reading works similarly (it behaves similar to `cout`, not so much to `scanf`). No formatting required:

```
char c;
std::cin >> c;
```

Here is an echo example:

```
char c;
while(std::cin >> std::noskipws >> c) {
    std::cout << c;
}
```

One caveat with `cin` is that it is stateful. If you've already used `cin` in your code, you may need to reset the error-state bits with `std::cin.clear()`

Comment: Please use one data type, preferably character.

Comment: I tried using this snippet in a simple `echo.c` program, but 1) whitespace was omitted and 2) the character never equated to `EOF`, so the program never halts.

Comment: @mcandre I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "Please use one data type, preferably character". Good point about whitespace. There is `noskipws` if you don't want to ignore it. The `>>` operator actually returns a reference to itself to support operation chaining. EOF is tested with `cin.eof()`. I've added an echo example.

Comment: The return value can actually be used as the loop condition because (bool)`std::cin` will evaluate to false when last read failed. That means there is one unnecessary iteration trying to read EOF as a char though.

Comment: @mcandre, you're welcome. Ignore my rambling about unnecessary iteration. Testing the return value in the loop condition is the idiomatic way as I've ended up showing in the example.

Comment: Assignment in conditionals is common in C, but I prefer not to for added robustness. If I can help it, I use languages that treat these as type errors (char is not a bool).

Comment: In that example, I'm not using the char as conditional. The value returned is `cin` itself which has a [well defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) meaning as a boolean. This appears to be a c++11 feature though, so if your compiler does not support that, you'll need to use `cin.eof()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are no formatters, there are different overloads of `operator<<`.

```
char c = 'a';
cout << c;
int i = 42;
cout << i;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just pass a char to an outstream, it will print as a char:

```
char a = 'a';
std::cout << a;
```

->

> a

If you want to output an `int` as a `char`, you can cast it:

```
int i = 'i';
std::cout << static_cast<char>(i);
```

->

> i

Answer (score 0):

Can't find any formatters, but this works:

```
int c = 'x';

cout.put(c);
```